# issues with Dask in python

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I have built a simple Dask application to use multiprocessing to loop through files and create summaries.The code is looping through all the zip files in the directory and creating a list of names while iterating through the files( Dummy task). I was not able to either print the name or append it in the list. what's the issue, i cant figure out.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ioff()
import time
import os
from  pathlib import Path
import glob


import webbrowser

from dask.distributed import Client

client = Client(n_workers=4, threads_per_worker=2) # In this example I have 8 cores and processes (can also use threads if desired)
webbrowser.open(client.dashboard_link)
print(client)
os.chdir("D:\spx\Complete data\item_000027392")
csv_file_list=[file for file in glob.glob("*.zip")]     
total_file=len(csv_file_list)

data_date=[]
columns=['Date', 'straddle_price_open', 'straddle_price_close']
summary=pd.DataFrame(columns =columns)



def my_function(i):
    df=pd.read_csv(Path("D:\spx\Complete data\item_000027392",csv_file_list[i]),skiprows=0)
    date = csv_file_list
    data_date.append(date)
    print(date)
    return date

futures = []

for i in range(0,total_file):
    future = client.submit(my_function, i)
    futures.append(future)

results = client.gather(futures)
client.close()
```

The idea is that I should be able to make operations on the data and print outputs and charts while using dask but for some reason i can't.

Comment: There does not seem to be any code for generating (and saving) images...

Comment: Since this is a batch job, I think you need to explicitly [disable](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#non-interactive-example) interactive mode for `pyplot`.  Also it's strange that you are using pandas inside a function, I would have used Dask dataframes.

Comment: I tried dask dataframe but they can't read zip files. so had to do it via pandas

Comment: @suvayu i turned off the interactive mode still it didnt save the images

Comment: I would suggest simplify your issue into a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit the question accordingly.  The way it is written now, it is very hard for anyone to help you.  Your [almost identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68820577/unable-to-save-a-plot-when-using-dask) got closed for this very reason.  Others need to be able to reproduce your problem to help you.

Comment: okay let me simplify